# how to change class value of HTML element by using flutter?

Tags: html, flutter

this is example HTML code (I ask for your understanding because I still have a lot of unfamiliar parts.)

```
<div>
<li class = "i" data = "a"> 
<li class = "i_on" data = "b"> 
<li class = "i" data = "c"> 
<li class = "i" data = "d"> 
<li class = "i" data = "e"> 
</div>
```

i want to change data d's class value "i" to  "i_on" & data a's value "i_on" to "i".

is there any way to change class value of HTML element by using flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that just using vanilla Javascript. The key here is how to select html elements having a given attribute value:

- querySelectorAll ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll))
- CSS Attribute selectors ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors))

While to change the value of the class attribute of a DOM element, you can directly access to its list of class through the `classList` property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)) and add and remove its items using the methods `add(classname)` and `remove(classname)`.

To clear the list of class of an element I used this strategy:

```
element.classList.remove(...element.classList);
```

`...` it's the spread operator and it's equivalent to passing all the elements of the array as a list of arguments to the remove function call -it's like: `.remove(element.classList[0], element.classList[1]..)`

Here's a commented example including a general function to factor that logic:

```js
//selects the li element having data attribute == "d"
let li_data_d = document.querySelectorAll('li[data="d"]');
//for each one of them,
li_data_d.forEach((el, i)=>{
  //from such element, removes the class i
  el.classList.remove('i');
  //from such element, adds the class i_on
  el.classList.add('i_on');
});

//selects the li elements having data attribute == "a"
let li_data_a = document.querySelectorAll('li[data="a"]');
//for each one of them
li_data_a.forEach((el, i)=>{
  //from such element, removes the class i
  el.classList.remove('i_on');
  //from such element, adds the class i_on
  el.classList.add('i');
});

//this to factor your logic in a generic function
//sets the class classToAdd to all the elements given by selector
//and removes as well any other class those elements had before
function setClassTo(selector, classToAdd){
  //grabs the elements given by the selector
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  //for each one of them
  elements.forEach((el, i)=>{
    //clears its classList
    el.classList.remove(...el.classList);
    //adds the classToAdd to the classList of the element
    el.classList.add(classToAdd);
  });
}

//Same task achieved with the general function (commented)
//setClassTo('li[data="d"]', 'i_on');
//setClassTo('li[data="a"]', 'i');
```

```css
.list{     
}
li{
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.i{
  background: darkgray;
}
.i_on{
  background: lightgray;
}
.i::after{
  content: 'Now: i class';
  float: right;
}
.i_on::after{
  content: 'Now: i_on class';
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <li class = "i" data = "a">A - Formerly class="i"</li>
  <li class = "i_on" data = "b">B - Formerly class="i_on"</li>
  <li class = "i" data = "c">C - Formerly class="i"</li>
  <li class = "i" data = "d">D - Formerly class="i"</li>
  <li class = "i" data = "e">E - Formerly class="i"</li>
</div>
```